# How do I prevent capital ships from attacking missile platforms?

Tags: sins-of-a-solar-empire

In Sins of a Solar Empire (any version), when I enter an enemy gravity well, my darn capital ships always attack missile platforms right off the bat.

This causes them massive damage and really tilts the odds of the battle against me.

Is there a way to tell these idiotic pilots to keep their distance from the platforms, by default?

I know I can steer them away manually, but I don't want to keep tabs on every individual battle every time it happens!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best bet may be to decrease their engagement radius to Near (or something like that) They won't ignore them completely, but they won't go haring off across the system to attack far-away platforms.

Comment: exactly, decrease engagement radius.  Besides, if you are sending capital ships into battle you should be paying more attention :P

Comment: Fair enough.  Usually I've got a fleet or two running around obliterating stuff.  I'll send them somewhere new, get distracted waiting for the phase jump, and then hear "Dumkoff has lost shields!" or similar, only to return and find these noble (and expensive) units have started something they can't finish.  Anyway thanks for the tip.

Comment: Same here. I usually make a fleet consisting of one of each type of capital, and have them wandering about taking new worlds.

Comment: Coming back to this question, this solution works pretty well.  It has the added benefit of keeping the capital ships near the edge of the gravity well so they can phase jump immediately if necessary (while their renewable squadrons do the dirty work).  At the start of the midgame phase, I set all my capital ships to "Hold Position" and they perform wonderfully.  Thumbs up!

Comment: Yep, it's especially helpful for carriers, for those exact reasons.